# Upgrading tomcat in xampp

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I've installet XAMPP in a windows VM, and I wanted to upgrade the tomcat from 7 to 8, I've pretty much got everything down, except one thing, I just realized that while tomcat 7 has a binary file "tomcat7.exe", apparently tomcat8 doesn't have one, and when XAMPP starts, it looks for the binary file, but since it's missing tomcat won't start.

Is there some config I could change so it starts from the catalina.bat and not from the binary file?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.
According to this
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/33j2l1/xampp_with_tomcat7_anyone_tried_to_upgraded_it_to/
you have to alter the tomcat version in the *xampp-control.ini* and the *catalina_service.bat*.

Additionally you may alter the *tomcat/tomcat_service_install.bat* and *tomcat/tomcat_service_uninstall.bat*.

Just to provide a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently the binary from the tomcat7 seems to do the work, I just changed the name of the binary to tomcat8.exe, placed it on xampp/tomcat, restarted it and it detected it, and starting tomcat didn't give me any problems and it seems to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I rename the tomcat7 in xampp to tomcat.bac and then copy the tomcat9 files there then copy the files in the tomcat.bac in the tomcat and skipped duplicated files.
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i  rename  the tomcat folder, was to https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi  and  dowload 64-bit Windows zip (pgp, sha512).

Uncompress the folder  and pateste  the new folder

[image]

[image]

Run perfect!

[image]